# How to reference different tabs in a single spread sheet document for variables - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is the proper way to reference multiple tabs in a spreadsheet? I am trying to modify data across two tabs. I have what I think is the proper logic for the modification, but I am not sure how to set the two tabs up with independent variables. Is modifying data across two tabs (within a single script) doable?

I was trying to do something like this:

```
var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above will return two `Sheet` objects: `s1` and `s2`, referring to Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively.

To modify data in these sheets, you need to define ranges for each sheet and use `setValue()` or `setValues()`:

```
var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var r1 = s1.getRange("A1");
var r2 = s2.getRange("A1");
r1.setValue('A');
r2.setValue('B');
```

You can check the different ways in which you can define ranges and get/set values to them in the official documentation:

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for the dumb question